# Hola cómo puedo acumular y sumar un resultado de un bucle en python, para sacar un promedio en python

Tags: python

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]La verdad no sé cómo hacer[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] el promedio me piden que haga el promedio si se cumplen dos condiciones, y eso está en un bucle, como acumuló lo resultados de cada ciclo?

```
pv = int(input("total personas a 
evaluar"))

acum = 0
ceis = li - lf
cet = ceis * pv
pcesr = acum / pv
li = lectura_inicial
lf = lectura_final

for(nc) in range(pv):
    nc = input("ingrese su numero de 
contrato: ")
    ts = input("tipo de suscriptor: 
  ")
    li = input("ingrese su lectura inicial")
    lf = input("ingrese su lectura final")

    if ts == "1" and ceis >= 500:
        acum = acum + 1
        primt("suscriptor r, con 
      alto consumo")

    else:
        pint("comercial")
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor edita tu pregunta e incluye to código como texto y no como imagen, de esa forma lo podemos copiar y pegar para que podamos ayudarte más rápidamente. También puedes clarificar qué promedio quieres calcular?

Comment: Enseguida gracias 

Comment: Bueno  el promedio que quiero calcular es es que el tipo de suscriptor (ts) su consumo de energía sea mayor a 500, cuando pasa esto se convierte en un suscriptor con consumo alto, el consumo se saca de la resta de la lectura inicial y la final

Comment: Entonces quiero saber cuál es el promedio de esas personas que su tipo de suscriptor sea 1, y su consumo sea mayor que 500,

Comment: Ok, podrías crear una lista vacía antes del ciclo `for` y adentro del `if` utilizar el método `append()`. De esa forma obtienes la lista que te interesa. Luego al terminar el `for` puedes calcular el promedio. Si usas los módulos numpy o statistics tienen métodos para calcular el promedio (`mean()`) o podrías utilizar los métodos `sum()` y `len()` si no quisieras importar módulos adicionales.

Comment: Toda la información relativa a la pregunta debe ir en la pregunta. Los comentarios se usan para dar detalles muy pequeños. Por favor agrega los detalles que has puesto en comentarios en tu pregunta, puedes hacer clic en [edit] para ello. Saludos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.